# No space between the number of a reference to an figure and the word "Figure"

Tags: floats, hyperref, color

After adding the following line to color links:

```
 \usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
```

my references' text started to looking odd: now the number of the figure is attached to the "Figure" word, i.e. "FigureX", for a certain number "X", instead of "Figure X".

I'm referring to the figure with:

```
\figurename{\ref{my_figure_label}}
```

How can I add a space between "Figure" and "X"?

Comment: Can you make a complete example demonstrating this? E.g., remove everything from the document except a figure and a reference to it, and as much as possible from the preamble.

Comment: Check if you need `some_name.sty` to reproduce the problem, if not then you just remove it from the example. If you need all the custom files to reproduce it, then I think you'll need to provide us with a link to them. How do you add cross references though? If there is some custom `\figref` macro or similar, then you could find the definition of that macro and at least show us that.

Comment: That `.sty` is just a bunch of packages and some definitions, you could just copy-paste the entire contents into your preamble, and then start trimming things down to a minimal example.

Comment: That said, `\figurename{} \ref{fig:a}`, and I don't think you would get a space there even without `hyperref`.

Comment: The only thing I don't have is `assignment.sty`, so I couldn't test with that. But with or without `\usepackage{some_name.sty}` and `hyperref` I get a space with my suggestion, and no space with yours. (In other words I have no way of answering without more info.)

Comment: `\figurename{\ref{my_figure_label}}` can't ever be the correct markup with or without hyperref, why not simply write `Figure \ref{my_figure_label}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hyperref` is not involved here.

`\figurename` does not take an argument and just expands to `Figure` (unless changed, by a class or language option) and `\ref` typically just produces a number such as `2`.

So

```
\figurename{\ref{my_figure_label}}
```

is the same  as

```
\figurename\ref{my_figure_label}
```

and produces

> Figure2

the simplest markup here is

```
Figure \ref{my_figure_label}
```

which, having a space after `Figure`, produces

> Figure 2

Comment: I strongly recommend to write `Figure~\ref{my_figure_label}` to prevent ugly linebreaks. Also, `\autoref` implemented by `hyperref` is useful to spare yourself writing `Figure` each time.

Answer (score 0):

In my document I used:

`\figurename\textbf{ }\ref{my_figure_label}` for figure,

`\tablename\textbf{ }\ref{my_table_label}` for table

since just having `\figurename   \ref{my_figure_label}` results in no space between word 'Figure' and number.

However, I wish there's a better way to do that.

Comment: `\anycommand  ` will swallow the spaces that come after, so that `\anycommand \anyothercommand` is equivalent to `\anycommand\anyothercommand`.  Try `\ ` (that is, slash space) where you want a space.